# How to position a dot right next to an icon?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

Hi, may I know is there got anyway to set the margin or padding closer to the iconUser, I want to get the circle shape at the top of the iconUser, been tried set margin or padding but still unable to solve this issues.

```
   children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(width: 10,),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: (){},
                      child: Image.asset("assets/ic_user_center.png",height: 16.0,width: 16.0,)
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 5.0,
                    height: 5.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.white
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use image instead of Icon, don't have to use stack to put dot on top right.

```
Container(
   width: 48,
   height: 48,
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      color: Colors.grey,
      image: DecorationImage(
         image: NetworkImage(imageUrl),
         fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
   ),
   child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
      child: Container(
         width: 20,
         height: 20,
         decoration: BoxDecoration(
         shape: BoxShape.circle,
         color: isOnline
            ? const Color(0xFF44B513)
            : Colors.grey,
         border: const Border.fromBorderSide(
            BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 3),
         ),
      ),
   ),
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Stack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liEGSeD3Zt8) and Positioned to specify where you want to place that white dot

Comment: can u try modify my code at above? Because BoxDecoration cannot cast in childen widget

Comment: Stack has 2 children: Positioned that wrap GestureDetector and sec Positioned that wrap Container with white dot. What problem are you facing?

Comment: Thank dude, i get what you mean now. Sorry, i am newbie to flutter

Comment: No worries) Have a great day

Comment: just migrate from native to flutter sir, still not very familiar to the code base of flutter

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var radius = 20.0;

  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: SizedBox.fromSize(
        size: Size.fromRadius(radius),
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: <Widget>[
            FittedBox(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.account_circle,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.black),
                width: radius / 2,
                height: radius / 2,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Instead of `Positioned`, you can also use `Align` with `alignment: Alignment.topRight`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to explore [Badges package](https://pub.dev/packages/badges)
This will be helpful to show online status, verified profile tag, unread messages count or any other easily.